# Why NodePort service is not accessible on Kubernetes Master node?

Tags: kubernetes, ingress, bare-metal, traefik

I have Kubernetes (1.28.2) cluster installed on baremetal VMs. One master and 2 worker nodes. I am using Calico pod network.

I have deployed a Traefik ingress with NodePort accessibility. Also deployed a very simple `whoami` service with one replica. I added the necessary ingress and  - I believe - every other configuration.

When I try to access the `whoami` service using the nodePort assigned to Traefik, it does not work from master. But only from Master, Because, when I address any of the worker nodes with the same nodeport, it works fine and I get the `whoami` response.

I use `firewalld` service, and all the necessary port are opened. But it does not really matter, because if I disable the firewall, the call is still timing out just like it does with the firewall turned on.

First, I tried to check the Traefik deployment access log, but nothing is written there when I address the master. (The log show the "routing" as expected, when I address the worker nodes). So, I thought, there must have been some issue with handling the packages. So, I tried to trace the iptables using the method described [here](https://vocon-it.com/2020/03/30/tracing-iptables-on-centos-cheat-sheet/), but basically, the log wasn't not moving and it looked like no packages had been hitting any rules/chains/anything on master when I targeted the nodeport on master.

Tell me what config do you want to see, in order to understand what is going on, and I will update this post!

Here are some of my configs in advance:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: traefik-account
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-role

rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
      - endpoints
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io
    resources:
      - ingresses
      - ingressclasses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-role-binding

roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: traefik-role
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: traefik-account
    namespace: default # Using "default" because we did not specify a namespace when creating the ClusterAccount.
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-dashboard-service

spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - nodePort: 32001
      port: 8080
      targetPort: dashboard
  selector:
    app: traefik
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-service

spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - nodePort: 32000
      targetPort: web
      port: 80
  selector:
    app: traefik
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-deployment
  labels:
    app: traefik

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-account
      containers:
        - name: traefik
          image: traefik:v2.10
          args:
            - --api.insecure
            - --providers.kubernetesingress
            - --accesslog
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 80
            - name: dashboard
              containerPort: 8080
```

Ports opened on my master (I'd like to use the application on por 32000):

```
  ports: 1903/tcp 6443/tcp 8080/tcp 10250/tcp 10251/tcp 10252/tcp 10255/tcp 2379-2380/tcp 5473/tcp 179/tcp 4789/udp 8285/udp 8472/udp 30000-32767/tcp
```

And the `whoami` ingress definition, which is supposed to work across the cluster:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whoami-ingress-test
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /whoamitest
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: whoami
            port:
              name: web
```

**Any help would be highly appreciated!**

Comment: Do you have any relevant network policies in place?

Comment: kubectl get networkpolicy -A returns "No resources found" @user23204747